Why my dependencies and plugins are so differenrt than of those on tutorials?
(https://i.sstatic.net/vTnZm0ro.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/JYKIkj2C.png)
They are so different than even on official websites I try using KSP dependencies but they are also different, I am new to android dev and it is really disheartening that I can't go beyond adding dependencies. why it can't be normal like [implementation "androidx.room:room-compiler-processing:2.6.1"]
I tried but can not able to find anything on forums or google, is this a new update ?

You are using a version catalog. That's the modern way to decouple the definition and the usage of a dependency. Follow the guide to migrate to version catalogs for more information.
